# How to check the connection with SSL sockets in java (client-server) using wireshark and other doubts

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, encryption, tcp

I need to develop a client-server desktop application with SSL sockets in Java. One of the requirements is to encrypt messages.

I'm trying out some internet example codes just to know how to make the encrypted connection.  The examples seem to work fine, or at least they do not generate errors, however I have to verify from Wireshark that messages are actually encrypted, but in wireshark I only see TCP packets. I have the certificates and keystores correct, in my opinion.

**JavaSSLServer.java**

```
/**
 @web http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/
*/    
public class JavaSSLServer {

static final int port = 8000;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/home/jose/serverKey.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","servpass"); 
    SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = 
            (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

    try {
        ServerSocket sslServerSocket = 
                sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("SSL ServerSocket started");
        System.out.println(sslServerSocket.toString());

        Socket socket = sslServerSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("ServerSocket accepted");

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                out.println(line);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Closed");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaSSLServer.class.getName())
                .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}}
```

**JavaSSLClient.java**

```
/**
 @web http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/
*/    
public class JavaSSLClient {

static final int port = 8000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/home/jose/clientTrustedCerts.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "clientpass"); 
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = 
            (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    try {
        Socket socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket("localhost", port);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while(true){
                System.out.println("Enter something:");
                String inputLine = scanner.nextLine();
                if(inputLine.equals("q")){
                    break;
                }

                out.println(inputLine);
                System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaSSLClient.class.getName())
                .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

}
```

I added the System.setProperty (...

**In Wireshark:**

[image]

**Other example:**

https://github.com/chuidiang/chuidiang-ejemplos-google-code/commit/2843dafc0a942c2dd636f7e2e1f9be6fe0b9e9ec

The results in Wireshark were similar.

I want to establish a connection with SSL sockets that encrypts the messages between the client and server, and that can be verified from Wireshark (that is another requirement).

My questions are:

- How do I verify that the message is actually encrypted using wireshark?
- Should I see SSL / TLS packets instead of TCP to conclude that they are encrypted?
- Can you tell me if some of the example code is wrong or incomplete?

Comment: Send a known message and see whether you can see it in Wireshark. That's the actual requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Your client and server are codes are exchanging plain text messages, so if you don't see that plain text in the TCP packets then the messages are likely being encrypted (which they should be, given the code shown).

To verify, you can filter the Wireshark capture on the two IP/Port pairs of the connection, then decode that TCP stream as `TLS`, and see if that succeeds. If so, it will show the first few packets of the connection (after the TCP 3-way handshake) are an unencrypted TLS handshake (exchanging the certificates and negotiating the encryption values), and the subsequent packets are encrypted TLS packets.